# NGUI in Unity 3D where to get skins

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

Hello Im a student and creating an Augmented Reality using Unity 3D,Im using NGUI in **Unity** for designing and i just wondering on where can I download some skins?? or where can I get it? i just want to use it on my Main menu, for UI designing purpose, also some skins for buttons, can someone know where can i get this?? and can I create a design in photoshop then export it and import in Unity? If someone has knowledge about this please let me know.thanks for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can create them yourself.

NGUI has a texture packer included.

1. NGUI => Open Atlas Packer => name your atlas and press create
2. select your images (buttons, background, sprites) in the Project Window and press "Add/Update All" inside the atlas maker
3. this will create the prefab where you can setup slicing etc for buttons

And also an font packer

1. NGUI => Open Atlas Packer
2. Drag in the font text file and the font texture (i using [bmGlyph](https://itunes.apple.com/app/bmglyph/id490499048) on OS X to create those)
3. Name the font and press "Create the Font" in the Font Maker Window
4. this will create the font prefab that you can use in your UILabel

Comment: Thankyou for the info sir, i have a question, What is the format of the photo that i will use as my background?? is .jpg working??

Comment: any image format is fine, but unity/ngui will convert it a different format, depending how you configure it and depending on the target plattform